# want to change the default directory structure of web application in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

In Eclipse, the folder structure when I create a Dynamic Web Project is

.: build src WebContent

./build: classes

./build/classes:

./src:

./WebContent: index.html META-INF scripts WEB-INF

./WebContent/META-INF: MANIFEST.MF

./WebContent/scripts: jquery-1.7.1.js

./WebContent/WEB-INF: lib web.xml

./WebContent/WEB-INF/lib:

As you can see, there is WebContent directory containg web-inf and other files, if I moved all the directories and files of WebContent directory a level above, it does not work, what to do to run the index.html in eclipse

-> the directory structure after moving all the directories and files of WebContent directory a level above:

.: build index.html META-INF scripts src WEB-INF

./build: classes

./build/classes:

./META-INF: MANIFEST.MF

./scripts: jquery-1.7.1.js

./src:

./WEB-INF: lib web.xml

./WEB-INF/lib:

So, now I need just go to "http://localhost:8080/Sample" and should go to index.html properly what path changes need to be done to make it run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "what to do to run the index.html in eclipse" and what you are referring to by "sample" in the URL that you provided, but here are some thoughts:

1. as a part of JavaEE specification, you must follow a specific directory structure and you can't fight it. For more info:
   http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gexap.html

In other words, you can call "webContent" whatever name you want, but you can't move it's content outside of that directory. Web-INF and your pages must be in a directory (of whatever you want to call it)

1. If your concern is to simply get to index.html from "http://localhost:8080/Sample", then you can do so by configuring web.xml and context root of your application as such:

In your  web.xml file (inside your Web):

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In your application.xml file (inside your EAR):

```
<web>
  <web-uri>YourWebModule.war</web-uri>
  <context-root>sample</context-root>
</web>
```

Then pinging servername:port/sample will redirect you to servername:port/sample/index.html

hope I addressed the question correctly

Comment: Do you have an EAR file? it's in there

so when you deploy your module, you package it with an EAR file, correct? An EAR File must have an application.xml file there. I use eclipse too and it generates a default one for me.